# php sessions are not being saved

Tags: php, session

I apologize for the wall of text but I've been banging my head against the wall around this problem for awhile so I'm gonna try to provide as much information as possible.
I'm not quite sure if the problem I'm getting has to do with user sessions (I'm new to PHP), but that's what it seems to me.

I ask a user to enter his login information (id and password) to enter the system in **ask_login.php**:

```
<div class="login_box">
        <h1>Login</h1>
        <form method="POST" action="login.php">
        <p><input type="text" name="username" placeholder="UserID"></p>
        <p><input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"></p>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login"></p>
        </form>
</div>
```

If the login details (id and password) are found in the database the user gets logged in to his user portal **(login.php)** where he can check his details, exams dates, etc..
My problem is whenever I login, if I click for example on the details button to check the user details, it redirects me to my ask_login.php page asking for my login details again saying that I didn't enter any ID/Password details.
I've tried removing the code where it checks if the login forms were submitted blank, and it eventually started working and I was able to click the 'Details' button or any other button, without getting redirected to ask_login.php.
But now when I click on the 'Details' button my "Welcome, username" line doesn't show the username, which makes me think that it has something to do with php sessions. Furthermore, any query that I make won't show the result.

Here's my **login.php** code:

```
<?php
session_start();


$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if($username && $password) {
  $conn_error = 'Could not connect.';
  $mysql_db = '------';
  if(!mysql_connect('localhost', '------', '') || !mysql_select_db($mysql_db)) {
  die($conn_error);
}
  $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$username' AND password='$password'");

    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);

      if($numrows!== 0) 
      {
          while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
          {
            $dbusername = $row['id'];
            $dbpassword = $row['password'];
          }

          if($username==$dbusername && $password==$dbpassword) {
            //echo "You are logged in!";
            @$_SESSION['id'] = $username;
          }
          else {
            echo "<script>alert('Username/Password are incorrect');</script>";
            echo "<script language='javascript'>window.location = 'ask_login.php';</script>";
            die();
            //die("Wrong username/password!");
          }
      }
        else {
            echo "<script>alert('User doesn't exist.');</script>";
            echo "<script language='javascript'>window.location = 'ask_login.php';</script>";
            die();
           //die("That user doesn't exist!");
         }
}

    else if(empty($username) || empty($password)) {
   echo "<script>alert('You didn't enter an ID/Password');</script>";
    echo "<script language='javascript'>window.location = 'ask_login.php';</script>";
    die();
    //die("Please enter an ID and password!");
}

?>



<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Logged in | FCUL</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet_loggedin.css" type="text/css"/>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/vitor-20130904-favicon.ico"/>
</head>


<body>

            <div id="header">
                <br/>
                    <a href="index.php"><img src="/img/fcul_cent_logo_001.png" width="510" height="70"/></a>
            </div>


<div id="loggedinas">
<br/>

Welcome, 
<?php 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT nome FROM users WHERE id='$username'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row["nome"];
} 
?> 

( <?php echo $username;  ?> ) 
 <br/>


 <div id="logout">
 <a href="logout.php"><font size="2"><u>[Logout]</u></a></font></a>
</div>

<hr/>
</div>



 <?php
//FETCH USER'S BI
    if(isset($_POST['username'] )) {

    $ID = $_REQUEST['username'];

  $query = "SELECT bi FROM users WHERE id='$ID'";

      //if query is successful
    if($query_run = mysql_query($query)) {

      //if it returns 0 rows
    if(mysql_num_rows($query_run)==NULL) {
    echo "<script>alert('Unexpected Error 004');</script>";
    echo "<script language='javascript'>window.location = 'index.php';</script>";
    }

      while($query_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run)) {
      $bi = $query_row['bi'];
      //echo $bi;
      }
  } 
}

?>



<br/>
<center>
<div id="buttons">

<form method="POST" action="login.php">
   <input type="submit" name="details" value="details">
    </form>

<?php
//**print user's BI if he clicks on 'Details' button**
    if($_POST['detalhes']){
    echo '<div id="content">' . $bi . '</div>';
}
?>


</div>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: regarless of the problem this code is insercure

Comment: What are the values of $username and $password? Anyway you should use ids in your form and note that your site is very easy to inject because you're not using prepared statements and mysql_* has been deprecated for a looong time.

Comment: Seems to me once you get past $numrows, we know the username and password matches at least 1 row so we can just use $username and $password. Also look into SQL input sanitation.

Comment: Please do not use javascript to redirect user to ask_login.php if javascript is disabled they can access all the things below the javascript redirect. just use header('location: file.php'); exit;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot access session on first time you insert it in $_SESSION['id'] = $username variable.
you can only access it on the second run of session_start();

try this.
1. make login.php
2. make welcome.php

try to separate the module where login.php will only process for checking 
the login process then if this condition success then

```
<?
if($username==$dbusername && $password==$dbpassword) {
    //echo "You are logged in!";
    $_SESSION['id'] = $username;
    header("location: welcome.php");
}
?>
```

in welcome.php

```
<? 
session_start();
// this is for the checking if user is loged in
if (!$_SESSION['id']) {
 header("location: ask_login.php");
 exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: I did exactly that, but the username still doesn't show up and my querys are not returning anything.. I tried printing the session and it actually returned me the correct ID. I have no clue why it won't work.

Comment: i think this is the problem,
you click the submit button and go to login.php
ofcourse inside the checkdetails form submit there is no password and username thats why you always redirect to ask_login.php with the message of you did not input username and password
try to wrap this part of your code


if (!$_POST['details'])
{
 if($username && $password) {
 
 }

}

Comment: Hey, just to update you. I managed to get it working. I separated the login into different modules: ask_login.php, login.php, main.php.
My problem was that I wasn't calling session_start() correctly in every page. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are not checking if the user is already logged, so, after receiving your post from ask_login.php, when you click anything in your page $username and $userpassword will be null.

Just wrap all your code after session_start with

```
if($_SESSION['id'] === false)
{

    //Your code
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    if($username &&...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

wrap your code with this

```
if ($_SESSION['id']){
//your login checking here
};
```

e.g

```
if ($_SESSION['id']){
if($username && $password) {
  $conn_error = 'Could not connect.';
  $mysql_db = '------';
  if(!mysql_connect('localhost', '------', '') || !mysql_select_db($mysql_db)) {
  die($conn_error);
}
  $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$username' AND password='$password'");

    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);

      if($numrows!== 0) 
      {
          while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
          {
            $dbusername = $row['id'];
            $dbpassword = $row['password'];
          }

          if($username==$dbusername && $password==$dbpassword) {
            //echo "You are logged in!";
            @$_SESSION['id'] = $username;
          }
          else {
            echo "<script>alert('Username/Password are incorrect');</script>";
            echo "<script language='javascript'>window.location = 'ask_login.php';</script>";
            die();
            //die("Wrong username/password!");
          }
      }
        else {
            echo "<script>alert('User doesn't exist.');</script>";
            echo "<script language='javascript'>window.location = 'ask_login.php';</script>";
            die();
           //die("That user doesn't exist!");
         }
}

    else if(empty($username) || empty($password)) {
   echo "<script>alert('You didn't enter an ID/Password');</script>";
    echo "<script language='javascript'>window.location = 'ask_login.php';</script>";
    die();
    //die("Please enter an ID and password!");
}
}
?>
```